# couchdb how to list all users on db?

Tags: curl, couchdb

I'm trying to determine what users have been created.

is there a curl command in couch to list all existing couchdb users?

if so what is it is that curl call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

curl gets all users as documents, grep extracts documents `_id`, sed strips `org.couchdb.user:` prefix and sort removes duplicates that comes from view result:

```
curl -s http://localhost:5984/_users/_all_docs | grep -o 'org.couchdb.user:[[:alnum:]]\+' | sed -n -e 's/org.couchdb.user:\(.*\)/\1/p' | sort -u
```

Note, that since 1.2.0 release if you had fixed Admin Party on server, you need to pass CouchDB admin credentials to make such requests for `_users` database.

Answer (score 7):

Use `_all_docs`, the following command lists all docs info of a specific database, just specify database name then you are done:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/<db_name>/_all_docs
```

Then replace `<db_name>` with `_users`, and use port 5986 since `_users` is a system table under port 5986:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5986/_users/_all_docs
```